# How to show plugin item info in TYPO3's plugin insertion page?

Tags: php, typo3

I created a little image gallery management plugin.
I can insert my own plugin to a page, but I miss some point.
When I insert a plugin in a page, I want to show info there to be easier to track all items added.
This is the page where I want to show previews:
[image: Typo3 page's plugin summary]

Under CODE: section, I am sure I can put content, but don't know which is the method or config to do that.

I will appreciate any hint regarding this.

UPDATE: I am using FlexForms, and not TypoScript nor things like that. What I am looking for is some Hook or some special configurable method to execute a PHP function to output things there.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://buzz.typo3.org/people/steffen-kamper/article/render-custom-preview-from-extension for a tutorial how to create your own plugin preview in the typo3 page view.

Comment: Many MANY thanks, I was crazy googling with no success, but that's exactly what I need :)